# $LC$ in parallel with $R$ circucit resonance

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance, resonance

I've been doing an experiment which involves measuring the voltage across the capacitor at different driving frequencies.
Consider the circuit below:

[image]

A sketch of the experimental curve $(R_1<R_2<R_3)$ with $(L,C)$ constant:

[image]

However I am still trying to understand why resonance takes place in the first place.
My logic is as follows:

$V_L$ and $V_C$ are in antiphase with each other (the inductor is in phase with the capacitor), so the voltage of the LC combination and hence the voltage of the circuit is:
$$V=V_L-V_C$$
$V$ is in phase with $I_R$.
The circuit current is
$$I=\sqrt{I_{LC}^2+I_R^2}$$
$$\frac{V}{Z}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{V}{Z_{LC}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{V}{R}\right)^2}$$.
Since $V=V_{LC}=V_L-V-C$, $I_{LC}Z_{LC}=I_{LC}X_L-I_{LC}X_C$,
$$Z_{LC}=X_L-X_{C}$$
$$\frac{1}{Z}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{(X_L-X_C)^2}+\frac{1}{R^2}} \to Z=\frac{|X_L-X_R|R}{R^2+(X_L-X_C)^2}$$
For resonance, $X_L=X_C \to Z=0$.
But $Z=0$ would lead to $I \to \infty$ so something isn't right with my derivation for $Z$ (circuit impedence)?

Also, I have been given the amplitude of the resonance peak:
$$A=\frac{k}{\sqrt{(\omega^2-\omega_0^2)^2+(\gamma \omega)^2}}$$
where $k$ is some normalisation factor, $\omega=2\pi f$ and $\gamma$ is the damping coefficient.
For $A$ to increase with $R$, am I correct to assume that $\gamma \propto \frac{1}{R}$? Is there a differential equation to describe the circuit?

EDIT:
The voltage source has an internal reactance of $600 \Omega$, $R_1,R_2,R_3=1,2,3 \Omega$
I obtained the folliwing differential eq.:
$$\ddot{I}_{LC}(t)+\frac{1}{L}\frac{R_{output}R}{R+R_{output}}\dot{I}_{LC(t)}+\frac{I_{LC}(t)}{LC}=\frac{RV_0 \omega cos(\omega t)}{(R+R_{output})L}$$, where $\omega$ is the driving angular frequency and $V_0$ is the peak driving voltage. This means $\gamma=\frac{R_{output}R}{L(R+R_{output})}$ even if the output resistance is taken into account, but wouldn't higher R lead to higher $\gamma$ and hence lower amplitude?($R_{output}=\text{internal r in the source voltage}$)

Comment: Why are you keeping it all real-valued? Let $V_R=V_L+V_C$ where the latter two are complex-valued (and so it the former, in principle). $I=I_R+I_{LC}$, again all complex-valued. $Z_R=R$, $Z_L=i\omega L$, $Z_C=1/i\omega C$. Alternatively keep all real-valued, but allow for time-dependence and solve differential equations

Comment: @ I have not yet studied AC theory in complex variables.

Comment: Did you study AC theory in time-domain via differential equations? This could be an alternative.If not, then I don't think I can explain this very well. I am sure some electrical engineers could (so it may a good idea to try their forum if you don't get a good answer here). If it is possible I would suggest investing time in learning AC in complex variables. It is not that difficult for resistors/inductors/capacitors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance#Inductor_and_capacitor, and it will cover most of your needs for these types of questions

Comment: In the circuit as drawn, and assuming *ideal* circuit elements (as you have), the resistor is 'invisible' to the L and C, i.e., the current through the series connected L and C does not depend on R and, in fact, the series LC current diverges when the circuit is driven on resonance. It would take a *series* resistance to limit the current on resonance such as, for example, a non-zero internal source resistance $r_S$ and/or a non-zero internal inductor resistance $r_L$.

Comment: @Cryo Thanks. But I got the same expression for Z with complex variables (after taking the magnitude)?

Comment: @Alfred Centauri So my expression for Z is correct because the current diverges? Why does the amplitude increase with resistance though?

Comment: As I suspected, the voltage source has an output resistance (not reactance) that you haven't accounted for in your schematic or calculations. An easy approach to solving this is to find the Thevenin equivalent circuit to the left of the inductor which will leave you with a Thevenin source driving a series RLC circuit where the series resistance is given by $R_{th} = 600\Omega || R_i$, $i=1, 2, 3$

Comment: @Alfred Centauri  I see. But I got a differential equation which looks like $\ddot{I}_{LC}(t)+\frac{1}{L}\frac{R_{output}R}{R+R_{output}}\dot{I}_{LC(t)}+\frac{I_{LC}(t)}{LC}=\frac{RV_0 \omega cos(\omega t)}{(R+R_{output})L}$, where $\omega$ is the driving angular frequency. This means $\gamma=\frac{R_{output}R}{L(R+R_{output})}$ even if the output resistance is taken into account, but wouldn't higher R lead to higher $\gamma$ and hence lower amplitude?

Comment: There are two factors to take into account but you're only taking into account one of these. Yes, higher $R$ *increases* the series resistance thus increasing the damping. But higher $R$ also increases the effective source voltage which acts to increase the amplitude. The Thevenin source voltage is $V\frac{R}{R + 600}$.

Comment: @Alfred Centauri Thanks. Just to clarify, my $R$ is the resistance of the external resistor (in parallel with LC) but I guess that's what you meant.